# my ext3 to ext4 dont work

Tags: ext4, ext3

my tools on centos 5.11

1. kernel - 3.2.69
2. util-linux-ng-2.17 ( mount 2.17 )
3. e2fsprogs-1.41.14
4. grub-1.97

this tool and kernel are all working

- my steps

  1. boot on recovery
  2. change the fstab (/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /  ext4 defaults        1 1)
  3. mount -o remount,ro /
  4. e2fsck -pf /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
  5. tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
  6. e4fsck -yfD /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00

and dont work, kernel panic dont mount my LogVol00

the error is:

EXT3-fs (dm-0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (40)

mount: error mounting /dev/root on /sysroot as ext3: Invalid argument

what i'm doing wrong  ? or what i'm missing ?

Answer (score -1):

fix my problem

recompile the kernel without EXT3 fs

and now kernel calls the EXT4-fs

but why with EXT3 and EXT4 the kernel calls EXT3-fs ???